# При компиляции в AndroidStudio (Shift+F10) перестала срабатывать RebuildProject

Tags: android-studio

Запускаю проект по Shift+F10.

Раньше автоматически происходил RebuildProject, теперь приходится запускать вначале его, а потом, чтобы запустить на устройстве, Shift+F10.
Почему это произошло?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить опцию `Gradle - aware Make` если она отсутствует в `Run`-> `Edit Configurations`->`Android App/app` ->`General` -> `Before launch` -> `+`

Comment: Проверил, она там есть. Но все равно спасибо. Мне кажется я что-то снес в build.gradle, но что именно не знаю.